# Including a JSP file that has its own CSS

Tags: java, css, jsp, model-view-controller, jersey

I have a simple JSP file which should show a banner/header and one line of text.
As the banner will be replicated across the website I would prefer to keep it and its CSS properties seperate so I've done the following:

**index.jsp**

```
<body>
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
    <p>The service is running and accessible <a href="/rest">here</a></p>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

**header.jsp**

```
<head>
    <link href="style/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="banner_container" class="center">
            <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_container" class = "center">
            <div id="menu_content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have the css header properties stored in `styles/header.css`. If I load header.jsp directly in a browser (not via my java app) this loads fine as expected:

[image: Accessing header.jsp directly in a browser]

In my web app i'm using Jersey to return a Viewable of index.jsp using:

```
@GET
public Viewable getIndex() {
    return new Viewable("/index");
}
```

All that I get when I load that endpoint in a browser is index.jsp without the banner or any css styling (See below). What am I missing?

[image: accessing index.jsp through my java web app]

**Output HTML for index.jsp**

```
<head>
    <titleTitle</title>
    <link href="style/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <head>
        <link href="style/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="banner_container" class="center">
            <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_container" class = "center">
            <div id="menu_content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
    <p>The service is running and accessible <a href="/rest">here</a></p>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: try: `<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>`. This is what I use and it pulls in all the CSS and everything

Comment: And what does the output HTML look like?  Surely it is invalid as the head and body of the include are in the body tag output by index.jsp?

Comment: @AlanHay you're correct, the output HTML is all wrong. How can I fix this using two jsps? I updated the question with the output html

Comment: You have two body tags. Your header can have the open body tag and the index could have the end one. Also, the open element for "title" isn't closed properly

Comment: My guess is that the Jersey servlet conflicts with the default servlet that serves the static content. Looking at your previous post you have the servlet mapping as `/*` for the Jersey servlet. This is the mapping used for the default servlet. What happens after the page is rendered, the browser will make another request for the css page, after it sees the `<link>`. When it tries to access the css page, it will encounter the Jersey servlet instead of the default servlet. I'm sure if you used a tool like Firebug for Firefox, you will see another request being made for the css page and...

Comment: ... report a Not Found. If this is the case, I guess a solution would be to use a different mapping for the Jersey servlet, like `/rest/*`, instead of `/*`

Comment: There are libraries such as http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Home or Apache Tiles that you could consider. Or maybe just use simple jsp tag files http://wiki4.caucho.com/Java_EE_Servlet_tutorial_:_Using_JSPs_to_create_header,_footer_area,_formatting,_and_basic_CSS_for_bookstore